# AS3 Loading Fonts from External SWF - Some work, some do not

Tags: actionscript-3

I have saved a dozen Fonts into separate swf files (embedded in the library of their respective .fla files). I am loading up to four of them and whilst most of them work, the script silently fails for Arial and Times New Roman. These fonts have been embedded and compiled the same as the others, and when I trace the available fonts I get an object saying that the required font has been loaded (`[Object { fontName="Arial", fontStyle="regular", fontType="embedded"}]`), however the text is not being rendered. If I change which font to use then the text is rendered using the correct font and performs as expected. It is only with these two fonts that I have a problem with.

Is there a common problem with embedding these two fonts or is it possible I have changed a setting somewhere?

Comment: Have you included the fonts for each of the styles/variations you want to use?  Italicized and/or bold fonts require an extra symbol...

Comment: Both Arial and Times New Roman are common system fonts and web fonts. I don't think it's necessary to embed them.

Comment: weltraumpirat Yes, I have (I am only using regular and bold versions of both fonts). Corey I agree however it is better to supply them just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by me using these fonts in the fla file, the Arial as text on a play/replay button, and Times New Roman as preloader text ('loaded xx%').

My application refused to re-register the fonts as they were already embedded / in use.

My solution?

I 'broke apart' the text on the buttons and made them into a symbol, then removed the preloader text (client didn't want text anyway, just a spinner) and lo and behold my application applies the required fonts. It would have been nice if there was a trace or exception thrown or SOMETHING to let me know that these fonts had already been pre-registered. Oh well. Live and learn.